# Focus not getting set on a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've a C#/WPF application.On my view,I need to set focus on a combobox on click of Clear button.
My code is as per below and I dont see focus getting set on the combobox.Could you advise what am I missing here please?

Thanks.

MyView:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboManager" Grid.Column="2" IsEnabled="{Binding EnableManagerView}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="195" Height="22" SelectedItem="{Binding MyViewModel.SelectedManager}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModel.Managers}" Style="{DynamicResource ManagerStyle}" Text="{Binding MyViewModel.Manager}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="Code" TabIndex="1"/>
```

MainWindowResources.cs:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FocusOnDealManager}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=cboManager}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
```

MyViewModel:

```
private void Clear()
{

 this.FocusOnDealManager = true;
}
public bool FocusOnDealManager
        {
             get; set; 
        }
```

Note: MyViewModel class inherits ViewModelBase which implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface.
Other functionalities like setting background color on a textbox,etc. using style are working.Its just that the focus on combobox is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to implmenet INotifyPropertyChanged, and raise if from your FocusOnDealManager property.

Comment: Thanks.Yes, my MyViewModel already does that.Have updated my question.

Comment: Are there any binding errors in the Output Window when you click the Clear Button?